# updateOne - filter one field, push or update sub field, add/update counter

Tags: mongodb

I want to track tags frequency within a period. How do I update (counter, updateDate) the array if found, otherwise push to field?

```
const date = new Date();
const beginMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
   await Tags.updateOne(
        { tag },
        {
            $set: {
                tag,
                period: {
                   // should have $cond: [{ $in: [beginMonth, "$period.createDate"] }]
                    $push: {
                        "createDate": beginMonth,
                        "updateDate": date,
                        "counter": 1,
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { upsert: true }
    )
```

it should have a condition to check if `{ $in: [beginMonth, "$period.createDate"] }` then `{$inc: {counter:1}` else `$push`. Also read that `upsert` cannot be used like this. How do I achieve this?

example:
If `world` tag exists and `createDate` is in `beginMonth` (August 1, 2021), then update counter to 2 and updateDate.

Let `food` tag does not exists, so it would push `createDate`,`updateDate`,`counter`

Before update:

```
{
  tag: 'world',
  period: [{
   createDate: 2021-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,
   updateDate:2021-08-28T13:16:58.508+00:00,
   counter:1
  }]
}
```

After update:

```
[{
      tag: 'world',
      period: [{
       createDate: 2021-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,
       updateDate:2021-08-28T14:16:58.508+00:00,
       counter:2
      }]
    }
{
      tag: 'food',
      period: [{
       createDate: 2021-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,
       updateDate:2021-08-28T14:16:58.508+00:00,
       counter:1
      }]
    }]
```

`createDate` probably bad naming, should be beginningDate. I am trying to tally tag frequency by month and keeping track of latest update for this period.

Comment: could you provide some sample data before and after update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$ifNull` to check input field is null then return a blank array
- `$cond` to check `beginMonth` is in array `period.createDate`
- condition is true then,

  - `$add` to increment number in `counter`
  - `$map` to iterate loop of `period` array and check condition if `beginMonth` is `period.createDate` then increment `counter` otherwise nothing
  - `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated `counter` property
- else,

  - `$concatArrays` to concat current period array with new input object
- `upsert` will work because we have handled all the possible scenarios

```
const date = new Date();
const beginMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
await Tags.updateOne(
  { tag },
  [{
    $set: {
      period: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [beginMonth, { $ifNull: ["$period.createDate", []] }] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$period",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      { $eq: [beginMonth, "$$this.createDate"] },
                      { counter: { $add: ["$$this.counter", 1] } },
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              { $ifNull: ["$period", []] },
              [
                {
                  createDate: beginMonth,
                  updateDate: date,
                  counter: 1
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { upsert: true }
)
```

**Case 1:** tag exists, date exists, so incremenet counter 
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/10v-v_l8Pdb)

**Case 2:** tag exists, date not exists, so add the new element in period array 
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j2v5MlCbd-r)

**Case 3:** tag not exists, so add new document, this is the job of upsert 
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Not2f69VJ21)